# Deep and sparse vs. Thin and dense data collection for curve fitting?

Tags: sampling, experiment-design, curve-fitting

I'm designing a toy experiment in which I'd like to model the 'attractiveness' of a credit card as a function of the interest rate it comes with:

- Attractiveness will be reported on a 10 point scale
- I can vary interest rate between 0% and 25%.
- In total, I have budget  that will allow me to collect 1,000 data points, each of which will be a single human subject's attractiveness rating of the credit card for a single interest rate.

My question: Is it better to test more interest rate levels over this range, with fewer observations at each interest rate, or more interest rate levels over the range, and collect fewer observations at each level?

I think if I want to fit a straight line (e.g. using linear regression), then as long as I collect the same number of observations at each interest level, and 2 or more levels, it doesn't matter. However, I'm not sure what family of curves I'd like to fit, or where I'd find math to support this.

Thanks!

Comment: The linear situation is well understood: when you're *sure* the relationship is linear then the most precise fit is found by making half the observations at each extreme value of the independent variable (0% and 25%). The math is that of ordinary least squares. Your question is more interesting due to the complication of needing to figure out the shape of the curve. Good answers will capitalize on your *objectives*: presumably at some later point you will use this information to optimize a business objective (like profit). How exactly will you use your study results in that optimization?

Comment: Adding to whuber's comment, for non-linear models sometimes the "optimal" design relies on the true value of the model, which you're trying to estimate.  You can use a Bayesian approach to find the best mean design given some prior belief, which can sometimes smear the design points out.  So whereas first order linear models occupy one extreme (all observations at the extremes) there are non-linear models and optimality criteria that can occupy the other extreme (very spread out observations).

Comment: I don't have a business case in mind just yet, and frankly have (almost) no prior as this would be for an exploratory study. Even in the least squares case what